# How can I make my timeline faster everytime I click a button?

Tags: javafx

currently stuck with a problem in JavaFX, trying to create a cookie clicker game, so i've created a button "Clicker" which automatically, once every 5 seconds, clicks the cookie. Im trying to make my timeline 0.1 seconds faster everytime i buy another clicker, currently, i've been trying it like this:

```
        private double clickerSpeed = 5.1;

        Timeline clickerPoints = new Timeline();
        KeyFrame kfClicker = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(clickerSpeed), 
        event -> {
             cookieClicker.cookies += cookieClicker.cursor.getProdRate();
             cookieButton.setText("Cookies = " + cookieClicker.cookies);
        });
        clickerPoints.getKeyFrames().add(kfClicker);
        clickerPoints.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);


        buyClicker.setOnAction(event -> {
            if (clickerSpeed >= 1 && cookieClicker.cookies >= 
            cookieClicker.clicker.getCosts()) {
            clickerSpeed -= 0.1; ## In theory, this should make the keyframe faster?
            }
        cookieClicker.buyClicker();
        clickerLabel.setText(cookieClicker.clicker.getName() + "s: " + 
        cookieClicker.clicker.getLevel());
        buyClicker.setText("Buy clicker for: " + 
        cookieClicker.clicker.getCosts());
        cookieButton.setText("Cookies = " + cookieClicker.cookies);
        clickerPoints.play();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying a primitive `double` does not have any effect on values read before; the duration is not automatically adjusted.

To speed up the `Timeline` you should modify the `rate` property instead.

The following example shows how to update the duration an animation takes to animate fading a `Rectangle` from 10 seconds to 1 second in 1 second steps:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100);
    Button btn = new Button("Speed Up");
    HBox root = new HBox(rect, btn);
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(rect.opacityProperty(), 1d)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(10), new KeyValue(rect.opacityProperty(), 0d))
    );
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();

    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        private double duration = timeline.getCycleDuration().toSeconds();

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            if (duration > 1) {
                duration--;
                timeline.setRate(timeline.getCycleDuration().toSeconds() / duration);
            }
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```